# Resetting Accidental Changes on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I've run into a very annoying problem. I'm working on a Rails project that is hosted on Heroku, with the central repo hosted on Bitbucket. Unfortunately, I don't have access to a linux box, so I've been working in Windows, which has forced me to make all sorts of changes to the project (gem versions etc.) in order to get it to function in my local environment. Normally this isn't a big deal, as long as I don't push any of those changes to Heroku or Bitbucket. Today, however, I made some very small changes to a view in order to fix a bug (like 3 lines total), pushed those small changes to Bitbucket, and then made the mistake of accidentally pushing all of my changes to Heroku (along with a bunch of Aptana config files).

So I have a situation where I have a correct codebase on Bitbucket, a(n intentionally) screwed up local repo, and an accidentally screwed up Heroku server. In order to try an rectify the situation, I cloned the Bitbucket repo into an entirely new local repo and then tried to push that to Heroku. When I did so, I got an error indicating that my local repo was behind, so I tried to fix that with:

```
git pull heroku master
git reset master XXXthe_commit_I_want_reflected_on_herokuXXX --hard
git push heroku master -f
```

Unfortunately when I do that, Heroku is now failing to build. My site was up and running earlier this morning, so I know that the old codebase was fully functional. I know that the only changes between that fully functional commit and the one I'm trying to push are 3 lines in a view, so even if they aren't good changes they shouldn't break the build. I have no idea what is breaking the build now.

In the meantime, I've used Heroku's web gui to rollback to the last working build (the one before I pushed my Windows hacks), but I really need to get this working. Can anyone help?

Here's my Heroku build log

```
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.0
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.9.7
   Ruby version change detected. Clearing bundler cache.
   Old: ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-linux]
   New: ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-linux]
   Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
   Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.............
   Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
   Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
   Fetching git://github.com/Armor-Payments/armor_payments_ruby.git
   Fetching git://github.com/lacco/mailboxer.git
   fatal: Could not parse object 'd436329f771d1607a6835f0aeb8b1120a3562a47'.
   Git error: command `git reset --hard d436329f771d1607a6835f0aeb8b1120a3562a47`
   in directory
   /tmp/build_a5ee9a745f4daf14f284ecb5241f4bd2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bundler/gems/mailboxer-d436329f771d
   has failed.
   If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory
   '/tmp/build_a5ee9a745f4daf14f284ecb5241f4bd2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/cache/bundler/git/mailboxer-2227b0f1f9bdf29f4822c250264b96e64ed63013'
   Bundler Output: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.............
   Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
   Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
   Fetching git://github.com/Armor-Payments/armor_payments_ruby.git
   Fetching git://github.com/lacco/mailboxer.git
   fatal: Could not parse object 'd436329f771d1607a6835f0aeb8b1120a3562a47'.
   Git error: command `git reset --hard d436329f771d1607a6835f0aeb8b1120a3562a47`
   in directory
   /tmp/build_a5ee9a745f4daf14f284ecb5241f4bd2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bundler/gems/mailboxer-d436329f771d
   has failed.
   If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory
   '/tmp/build_a5ee9a745f4daf14f284ecb5241f4bd2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/cache/bundler/git/mailboxer-2227b0f1f9bdf29f4822c250264b96e64ed63013'
!
!     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
!
!     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

Comment: I figured out what was wrong and was able to push to Heroku, by comparing the Gem.lock files in my two local repositories. I noticed that somehow this entry got made in my new "clean" respository's Gem.lock:
`remote: git://github.com/lacco/mailboxer.git
revision: d436329f771d1607a6835f0aeb8b1120a3562a47`
The original "dirty" repository had this instead: 
`remote: git://github.com/lacco/mailboxer.git
revision: d4f0e9c70e29fcc5c2b4b7c87379e1830d45a367`
Replacing the first entry with the second allowed me to push to Heroku and my site is back up and running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future reference, the quickest way to go back to your last deployment is via:

```
$ heroku rollback
```

Docs here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/releases#rollback